# mockito InjectMocks not working?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I am trying to use a test implementation of a class and using that to be injected to the test using `@InjectMocks` but it doesn't seem to inject it. I tried using Spy but that did not work and instead created a blank mocked version instead of using the version I created inside my `@Before` function

Here is my test code below:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    someFunction = object : SomeFuntionContract {
        override fun save(test: String) {
            testData = test //breakpoint here but never executes
        }

        override fun get(): String {
            return testData
        }
    }
}

lateinit var testData : String

@InjectMocks
lateinit var delegator: Delegator


@Spy
lateinit var someFunction: SomeFunctionContract


@Test
fun testSomething{
    delegator.retrieve(something)

    Assert.assertTrue(someFunction.get() == "hello")
}
```

`SomeFunctionContract.kt` is an interface that has `save` and `get` functions and `SomeFunction` is the real implementation test

Inside `delegator.retrieve` it calls `someFunction.get` inside it and I am trying to see if it gets called and saves the data.

Comment: Please learn proper indentation and use it. I've fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you init the creation and injection of the mocks by:

**1)** Adding `@RunWith(org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner)` on the test class.

or

**2)** Adding `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` to your `@Before` method.

Comment: hi. yes i have already included @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class) on top of my test class

Answer (score 0):

The `@Before` method is called after `Mockito` does its injection magic so, you are overwriting the spy created and used by `Mockito`. If you want to have your own implementation of the object to be injected (I'm assuming it is `SomeFunctionContract`) then you have to declare it on the property instead of on the `@Before` function.

All that said, I think we are missing some context of your code. Can you attach the code for `something`, `Delegator` and `testData`?

Comment: Hi i tried initialising the object inside the test method and still i get an issue where it never fires the implemented someFucntion that i defined. The Delegator class has a @inject  lateinit var  someFunction : SomeFunctionContract that works in real time using dagger 2 but not when i try to add a mock implementation on it on my test code

Comment: o yes i got it working. under @spy lateinit var someFunction i set the test implementation directly there

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

initialise the implementation directly in the spy level:

```
@Spy
lateinit var someFunction: SomeFunctionContract =  = object : SomeFuntionContract {
        override fun save(test: String) {
            testData = test //breakpoint here but never executes
        }

        override fun get(): String {
            return testData
        }
    }
```

Comment: No need for `lateinit` and I'm sure you only need one equals